# Integrating LDAP with Glassfish and FTP

Tags: ssl, ftp, ldap, glassfish-3, suse

I'm currently faced with the task of integrating a glassfish environment and an FTP-Server with LDAP. This is work for an university, we need to be able to have a number of students(which all have Login-Data via LDAP, though access is only permitted via SSL) run their own applications on a glassfish server, upload them and then restrict their access at a given date.

I set up a Suse Enterprise 10 SP3-Server, configured it, installed a Java6-repository and Glassfish 3.0.1. Does anybody know whether there is a way to connecting Glassfish with LDAP and letting specified users upload specific programms? If upload is not possible I thought about simply setting up a FTP-Server and connecting that via LDAP, can anybody point me to a link on how to do that?

I obviously googled but getting information for Suse Enterprise 10 is actually very hard, wasted about an hour because I wanted Java 6-repos instead of compiling it via source.

thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1):

Glassfish rpms can be downloaded from opensuse build service http://software.opensuse.org/search

For Glassfish integration with ldap, [this](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/tchangu/archive/2007/01/ldap_security_r.html) might be of help